# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. c#.net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Class with Static and Readonly attributes

```
public class ClaSearchUser
{
    public ClaSearchUser() { }


    public struct Attributes
    {
        public static readonly Attribute EMAIL_ADRESS;
        public static readonly Attribute FIRST_NAME;
        public static readonly PuzzleAttribute STATUS;
    }
}
```

But when i make use of it I get that error in email line.

```
foreach (DataRow mRow in data.Table.Rows)
      {
        String id = mRow[AttributeManager.Common.Ident.Name].ToString ();
        String user_oid = mRow[AttributeManager.Common.Oid.Name].ToString ();
        String email = mRow[ClaSearchUser.Attributes.EMAIL_ADRESS.Name].ToString ();

      }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In which line is the error occurring?

Comment: One of your variables is null, is what the error says. Please place a breakpoint and walk through your code; we can't do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access member variables or methods of variables that are `null`.

Here is a list of all variables, that *might* be `null` and will throw that exception, if they are:

- **AttributeManager.Common.Ident**
- **AttributeManager.Common**
- **AttributeManager**
- **mRow[AttributeManager.Common.Ident.Name]**
- **AttributeManager.Common.Oid**
- **mRow[AttributeManager.Common.Oid.Name]**
- **ClaSearchUser.Attributes.EMAIL_ADRESS**
- **ClaSearchUser.Attributes**
- **ClaSearchUser**
- **mRow[ClaSearchUser.Attributes.EMAIL_ADRESS.Name]**

Which one truly *is* `null`, is your job to find out.

Answer (score 1):

`ClaSearchUser.Attributes.EMAIL_ADRESS.Name` will result in the given exception when you do not set `EMAIL_ADRESS` to a value.

Or it could be any of the other `Name`'s that you are trying to read.

Answer (score 1):

`ClaSearchUser.Attributes.EMAIL_ADRESS.Name` will throw a NullReferenceException, if EMAIL_ADRESS is null.
`mRow[ClaSearchUser.Attributes.EMAIL_ADRESS.Name]` could also be null, which would cause the `.ToString()` to throw a NullReferenceException.